# Помогите составить JavaScript-код для заданной формы

Tags: javascript

Нужно написать функцию, которая подсчитает количество нажатых checkbox

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Тест</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor=rgb(300,200,102)>
<form name=f1>
<center>
<h1><font face="Verdana" color = rgb(100,150,100)> Представление информации</h1>
</center>
</font>
<table border=5 bordercolor=rgb(100,150,100) width=85% align=center bgcolor=rgb(255,250,154)>
<tr>
 <td>
 <h3>
 <center><font face="Verdana" color=brown><i>
 1. Полный набор символов,используемых для кодирования, называют:<br></i></font>
 </center>
 </h3>
  <h4><font color = rgb(100,150,100)>
  <form name="f1">
  <input type="checkbox" value="1">шрифтом<br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="1">алфавитом<br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="1">синтаксисом<br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="1">сематикой<br>
  </form>
  </h4>
</td>
 </tr>
<tr>
 <td>
 <h3>
 <center><font face="Verdana" color=brown><i>
 2. Минимальным объектом, используемым для кодирования текста, является:<br></i></font>
 </center>
 </h3>
  <h4><font color = rgb(100,150,100)>
  <form name="f2">
  <input type="checkbox" value="1">бит<br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="1">пиксель<br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="1">символ<br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="1">растр<br>
  </form>
  </h4>
</td>
 </tr>
<tr>
 <td>
 <h3>
 <center><font face="Verdana" color=brown><i>
 3. Для кодирования одной точки монохромного изображения, имеющего 256 оттенков, требуется:<br></i></font>
 </center>
 </h3>
  <h4><font color = rgb(100,150,100)>
  <form name="f3">
  <input type="checkbox" value="1">1 бит<br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="1">3 бита<br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="1">1 байт<br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="1">3 байта<br>
  </form>
  </h4>
</td>
 </tr>
</table>
    <center>
        <button>Проверить</button>
        <input type="reset" value="Стереть"><br /><br />
        Результат<br />
        <input type="text" name="result" readonly>
    </center>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
    var checks = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');


    check.onclick = function(){
        var count = 0;

        checks.forEach(function (c) {
            if (c.checked == true){
                count += 1;
            }
        });
        document.getElementById('result').value =count;
    };
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Тест</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor=rgb(300,200,102)>
    <center>
        <h1><font face="Verdana" color = rgb(100,150,100)> Представление информации</h1>
    </center>
    </font>
    <table border=5 bordercolor=rgb(100,150,100) width=85% align=center bgcolor=rgb(255,250,154)>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <h3>
                    <center><font face="Verdana" color=brown><i>
                                1. Полный набор символов,используемых для кодирования, называют:<br></i></font>
                    </center>
                </h3>
                <h4><font color = rgb(100,150,100)>
                        <form name="f1">
                            <input type="checkbox" value="1">шрифтом<br>
                            <input type="checkbox" value="1">алфавитом<br>
                            <input type="checkbox" value="1">синтаксисом<br>
                            <input type="checkbox" value="1">сематикой<br>
                        </form>
                </h4>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <h3>
                    <center><font face="Verdana" color=brown><i>
                                2. Минимальным объектом, используемым для кодирования текста, является:<br></i></font>
                    </center>
                </h3>
                <h4><font color = rgb(100,150,100)>
                        <form name="f2">
                            <input type="checkbox" value="1">бит<br>
                            <input type="checkbox" value="1">пиксель<br>
                            <input type="checkbox" value="1">символ<br>
                            <input type="checkbox" value="1">растр<br>
                        </form>
                </h4>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <h3>
                    <center><font face="Verdana" color=brown><i>
                                3. Для кодирования одной точки монохромного изображения, имеющего 256 оттенков, требуется:<br></i></font>
                    </center>
                </h3>
                <h4><font color = rgb(100,150,100)>
                        <form name="f3">
                            <input type="checkbox" value="1">1 бит<br>
                            <input type="checkbox" value="1">3 бита<br>
                            <input type="checkbox" value="1">1 байт<br>
                            <input type="checkbox" value="1">3 байта<br>
                        </form>
                </h4>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <center>
        <button id="check">Проверить</button>
        <input type="reset" value="Стереть"><br /><br />
        Результат<br />
        <input type="text" name="result" id="result" readonly>
    </center>
</body>
```

Comment: @Sam Smith Да не за что. Вариант Igor чуть проще и быстрее.

Answer (score 5):

```
document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']:checked").length
```